# Removing time from dates in time column in 3 layer data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to remove "T00:00:00" from the time columns from each of the 3 layers of my data frame in R. I am unsure how to do this. My data looks like the following:

```
[[1]]
# A tibble: 1 x 3

  observation HRpcode timeseries

        <int> <chr>   <chr>  

1           1 NA      NA    


[[2]]

# A tibble: 74 x 3

   observation time                ` NDVI`

         <int> <chr>               <chr>

 1           1 2014-01-01T00:00:00 0.3793765496776215 

 2           2 2014-02-01T00:00:00 0.21686891782421552

 3           3 2014-03-01T00:00:00 0.3785652933528299 


# ... with 64 more rows


[[3]]

# A tibble: 74 x 3

   observation time                ` NDVI`    

         <int> <chr>               <chr>    

 1           1 2014-01-01T00:00:00 0.4071076986818826

 2           2 2014-02-01T00:00:00 0.09090719657570319

 3           3 2014-03-01T00:00:00 0.35214166081795284


# ... with 64 more rows


[[4]]

# A tibble: 74 x 3

   observation time                ` NDVI` 

         <int> <chr>               <chr>     

 1           1 2014-01-01T00:00:00 0.3412131556625801 

 2           2 2014-02-01T00:00:00 0.18815996897460135

 3           3 2014-03-01T00:00:00 0.5218904976415136 


# ... with 64 more rows
```

How do I isolate columns and multipulate them please?

EDIT: Here is a sample of the data. I used dput(head(data)) to get a sample of the data but the command does not produce the 6 line samples I intended. Thus I have deleted some of the data so that I can post it on stack exchange. Thank you for the help.

```
list(Files = structure(list(observation = 1L, HRpcode = NA_character_, 
    timeseries = NA_character_), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")), Ra = structure(list(observation = 1:6, 
    time = c("2014-01-01T00:00:00", "2014-02-01T00:00:00", "2014-03-01T00:00:00", 
    "2014-04-01T00:00:00", "2014-05-01T00:00:00", "2014-06-01T00:00:00"
    ), ` NDVI` = c("0.3793765496776215", "0.21686891782421552", 
    "0.3785652933528299", "0.41027240624704164", "0.4035578030242673", 
    "0.341299793064468")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")), Ba = structure(list(observation = 1:6, 
    time = c("2014-01-01T00:00:00", "2014-02-01T00:00:00", "2014-03-01T00:00:00", 
    "2014-04-01T00:00:00", "2014-05-01T00:00:00", "2014-06-01T00:00:00"
    ), ` NDVI` = c("0.4071076986818826", "0.09090719657570319", 
    "0.35214166081795284", "0.4444311032927228", "0.5220702877666005", 
    "0.5732370503295022")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")), Tailevu = structure(list(observation = 1:6, 
    time = c("2014-01-01T00:00:00", "2014-02-01T00:00:00", "2014-03-01T00:00:00", 
    "2014-04-01T00:00:00", "2014-05-01T00:00:00", "2014-06-01T00:00:00"
    ), ` NDVI` = c("0.3412131556625801", "0.18815996897460135", 
    "0.5218904976415136", "0.6970128777711452", "0.7229657162729096", 
    "0.535967435470161")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `tidyverse` methods

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
list_df <- map(list_df, ~if('time' %in% colnames(.x)) {  
                         .x %>%
                             mutate(time = str_remove(time, "T.*"))}

                       else .x)
```

-output

```
list_df
#$Files
# A tibble: 1 x 3
#  observation HRpcode timeseries
#        <int> <chr>   <chr>     
#1           1 <NA>    <NA>      

#$Ra
# A tibble: 6 x 3
#  observation time       ` NDVI`            
#        <int> <chr>      <chr>              
#1           1 2014-01-01 0.3793765496776215 
#2           2 2014-02-01 0.21686891782421552
#3           3 2014-03-01 0.3785652933528299 
#4           4 2014-04-01 0.41027240624704164
#5           5 2014-05-01 0.4035578030242673 
#6           6 2014-06-01 0.341299793064468  

#$Ba
# A tibble: 6 x 3
#  observation time       ` NDVI`            
#        <int> <chr>      <chr>              
#1           1 2014-01-01 0.4071076986818826 
#2           2 2014-02-01 0.09090719657570319
#3           3 2014-03-01 0.35214166081795284
#4           4 2014-04-01 0.4444311032927228 
#5           5 2014-05-01 0.5220702877666005 
#6           6 2014-06-01 0.5732370503295022 

#$Tailevu
# A tibble: 6 x 3
#  observation time       ` NDVI`            
#        <int> <chr>      <chr>              
#1           1 2014-01-01 0.3412131556625801 
#2           2 2014-02-01 0.18815996897460135
#3           3 2014-03-01 0.5218904976415136 
#4           4 2014-04-01 0.6970128777711452 
#5           5 2014-05-01 0.7229657162729096 
#6           6 2014-06-01 0.535967435470161
```

Comment: I gave this a try but I got this error: '''Error in as.character(x) : cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'''

Comment: Solution 1 gives this error: Error in stri_replace_first_regex(string, pattern, fix_replacement(replacement),  : 
  argument `str` should be a character vector (or an object coercible to)

Comment: @eviep  Can you please update your post with a `dput` of a small example

Comment: @eviep I see that `more rows`.  For us to copy/paste, it needs the full output, otherwise it breaks in console.  May be you can subset a small example and dput

Comment: @eviep, You can  try `dput(lapply(head(l), function(x) droplevels(head(x))))`

Comment: Thank you! I did that!

Comment: @eviep can you check my update.  Found that some list elements doesn't have the 'Time' column

Comment: I have tried the update. It didn't create an error but it didn't change the data. The T times remain.

Comment: @eviep Okay, your column name was `time` instead of `Time`, can you check the update now

Comment: I'm thinking I may have to do a double loop? To loop through the regions and times. I don't have much experience but in python I would have done something like: 
```for in range 3:
       for x in range(len(l[[2]][2])):
               l[[i]][[2]][x] = l[[i]][[2]][x - "T00:00:00"] ```

Comment: @eviep you can check the output I got

Answer (score 0):

You could use `lapply` to loop over the lists and remove everything after `"T"`.

Assuming the list is called `list_df`, we can do

```
list_df <- lapply(list_df, function(x) {
     if("time" %in% names(x)) transform(x, time = sub('T.*', '', x$time))
     else x
})


list_df
#$Files
# A tibble: 1 x 3
#  observation HRpcode timeseries
#        <int> <chr>   <chr>     
#1           1 NA      NA        

#$Ra
#  observation       time              X.NDVI
#1           1 2014-01-01  0.3793765496776215
#2           2 2014-02-01 0.21686891782421552
#3           3 2014-03-01  0.3785652933528299
#4           4 2014-04-01 0.41027240624704164
#5           5 2014-05-01  0.4035578030242673
#6           6 2014-06-01   0.341299793064468
#...
#....
```

Comment: I've tired to do this but it throws an error: Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, time, value = character(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 1
In addition: Warning message:
 Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, time, value = character(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 1

Comment: @eviep It is difficult to reproduce the error on our end. Can you put the data using `dput` ? Please read the info about how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).